# Geohash Generator

Tags: code-golf, math, hashing

## XKCD Comic:[image]

---

## Goal:

Given a date, the current Dow Opening, and your current coordinates as a rounded integer, produce a "geohash."

## Input:

Input through any reasonable means (STDIN, function argument, flag, etc.) the following:

- The current date. This does necessarily have to be the date of the system's clock, so assume that the input is correct.
- The most recent Dow Opening (must support at least 2 decimal places)
- The floor of your current latitude and longitude.

To make input easier, you can input through any reasonable structured format. Here are some examples (you may create your own):

```
["2005","05","26","10458.68","37",-122"]
2005-05-26,10458.68,37,-122
05-26-05 10458.68 37 -122
```

## Algorithm:

Given your arguments, you must perform the "geohash" algorithm illustrated in the comic. The algorithm is as follows.

1. Format the date and Dow Opening in this structure: `YYYY-MM-DD-DOW`. For example, it might look like `2005-05-26-10458.68`.
2. Perform an md5 hash on the above. Remove any spacing or parsing characters, and split it in to two parts. For example, you might have these strings: `db9318c2259923d0` and `8b672cb305440f97`.
3. Append each string to `0.` and convert to decimal. Using the above strings, we get the following: `0.db9318c2259923d0` and `0.8b672cb305440f97`, which is converted to decimal as aproximately `0.8577132677070023444` and `0.5445430695592821056`. You must truncate it down the the first 8 characters, producing `0.857713` and `0.544543`.
4. Combine the coordinates given through input and the decimals we just produced: `37` + `0.857713` = `37.857713` and `-122` + `0.544543` = `-122.544543`

## Notes:

- To prevent the code from being unbearably long, you may use a built-in for the md5 hash.
- Standard loopholes (hardcoding, calling external resource) are forbidden.

Comment: May we take negative integers in the format `_#` instead of `-#`, i.e. `_37` instead of `-37`?

Comment: Yes. As I stated, input and output can be flexible.

Comment: Shame about not using built-ins. Python3's module antigravity would have works well https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/antigravity.py

Comment: @george Did you make that module?

Comment: @JulianLachniet Unfortunately not, never actually had a use for it though

Comment: @george Considering that module was created the day I posted the challenge, I'm a little bit suspicious.

Comment: @JulianLachniet That page was only updated on the 16th, not created luckily. I've know about the modules for a few years. https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/353:_Python suggests that is as old as 2.7.0, which was released in 2010. https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/

Comment: @JulianLachniet That module has been around for a while. I used it in [this answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/62939/34718) more than a year ago (just to be funny, though.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Bash + Coreutils + md5, 98 bytes:

```bash
C=`md5 -q -s $1-$2`;C=${C^^};for i in 3 4;{ dc -e 16i[${!i}]n`cut -c1-7<<<.${C:$[16*(i>3)]:16}`p;}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#DctBDoIwEADAr6xJD2qyhC1QCC1eeAYBmxSMPVCMyqn27SvJXIf7zi7uuQEGEIRC/ta5@uyr1X0nYj9NST@2N3jwAQoodYTZAS5Ayg8innwag3X7F9AR1saY7EitGEhdz/5WXMaWVLIvnZhZ5nmFB6mY8rJqMtVwUfOdpPwD)

Uses the built-in `md5` command on OSX to generate the MD5 hash. Takes 4 space separated command line arguments in the following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD DOW LAT LONG
```

with *negative numbers* input and output with a leading *underscore* (i.e. `_122` instead of `-122`).

**Note:** Depending on your system, you may need to substitute in `echo -n $1-$2|md5sum` for `md5 -q -s $1-$2` in order for this to work. Doing so brings the byte count up to 103, and is indeed the case in the TIO link.

Answer (score 5):

## Python 2, 129 bytes

```py
import md5
d,q,c=input()
h=md5.new(d+'-'+q).hexdigest()
print map(lambda p,o:o+'.'+`float.fromhex('.'+p)`[2:8],(h[:16],h[16:]),c)
```

Input is given in the form `'2005-05-26','10458.68',('37','-122')` (using the example).

Computes the MD5 hash with `md5.new().hexdigest()`, then performs the necessary transforms. I *could* save five bytes by using `h` instead of `h[:16]`, but I'm not sure if that would affect the six most significant digits in the decimal conversion.

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/QpgLgI) (substituting an `eval()` call for the `input()`)

Comment: BTW in python3 geohash is in the stdlib:`from antigravity import geohash`

Comment: `float.fromhex` can be `.0.fromhex`

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, <s>198</s> 161 bytes

```groovy
{d,o,l,L->m=""+MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest((d+"-"+o).bytes).encodeHex()
h={(Double.valueOf("0x0."+it+"p0")+"")[1..7]}
[l+h(m[0..15]),L+h(m[16..31])]}
```

This is an unnamed closure.

```
Input
f("2005-05-26","10458.68","37","-122")

Output
[37.857713, -122.544543]
```

[Try it here!](http://ideone.com/b2Mokj)

**Ungolfed** -

```groovy
import java.security.*
{
    date,open,lat,lon ->
    md = "" + MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5").digest((date+"-"+open).bytes).encodeHex()
    decimal = {(Double.valueOf("0x0."+it+"p0")+"")[1..7]}
    [lat+decimal(md[0..15]),lon+decimal(md[16..31])]  //Implicity returns
}
```

Comment: https://tio.run/nexus/groovy btw ;).

Comment: Also, ` as String` is shorter than `.toString()` by one byte.

Comment: @carusocomputing Thanks saved a lot by using this instead `""+..`.

Comment: Oh jeez! I shoulda seen that as well, haha that took it even further, nice one ☺.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript (Node, using built-in Crypto), 165 characters

```javascript
(d,o,l)=>l.map((p,i)=>p+Math.sign(p)*[...require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(d+-o).digest`hex`.slice(z=i*16,z+16)]
.reduce((a,d,i)=>a+parseInt(d,16)*16**~i,0))
```

Such a verbose API!

### JavaScript (using `md5` library), 125 characters

```javascript
(d,o,l)=>l.map((p,i)=>p+Math.sign(p)*[...require('md5')(d+-o).slice(z=i*16,z+16)]
.reduce((a,d,i)=>a+parseInt(d,16)*16**~i,0))
```

Nothing very golfy here.

In both cases:

````
f('2005-05-26', 10458.68, [144,-37])

=> [ 144.857713267707, -37.54454306955928 ]
```
````

Comment: Save 3 bytes with `d+-o`.

Comment: Oh, nice one :)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 185 bytes

```python
import hashlib as h
x,y,a,n=input().split(',')
b=h.md5((x+'-'+y).encode()).hexdigest()
q=list(map(str,map(float.fromhex,['0x.'+b[:15],'0x.'+b[16:]])))
print(a+q[0][1:8]+','+n+q[1][1:8])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NY9BaoYwFIT3nsJdEvIMia3-IngSySJWbQKa5Df5Qc_SjZv2DqUn6W2aYgsP5n0wwzBvH_6I2tnzfH_EuWi-P83q3RZzrYJezJCrkOtshwMU2M5Y_4iYsOAXEzECRLKh02wdK4x3igpED8Im--LGCRPC9LSP5nUKKZLdu8WkZ1Ueh7jBr86LU5HNm1uTEXrEd4bo0LeikvAPom6lJIRkfjM2YkXvPZe9aBtJUz21icXF5Brwt-P8KjmvinRlDYI_Vw2rG3i6QSHK8rL8AA)

Hashlib stole my bytes, :P.

Comment: I can recover those bytes, but you’ll need to pay a £10.00 fee.